# Magento 2 How to Setup (Amazon CloudFront CDN) Alternative Domain Name in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, aws, cdn, cloudfront-cdn

How to setup Alternative Domain Name in CDN setup Using AWS(Amazon)?

Answer (score 0):

Create AWS Account to start setting up then create a distribution,
after that set up access-control-allow-origin for the static files & media,
create A new URL for static and media.

Hope this information will be helpful to you.

Comment: I followed all these steps but i am facing error while setting Alternative Domain Name...Can you help me about how to setup Alternative Domain Name.